# Convert byte to string of bits in z/OS Assembler?

Tags: assembly, mainframe, zos

What is the best way to convert a byte to it's bit representation in z/OS Assembly?

E.g. X'3A' becomes CL8'00111010', similar to the intrinsic function BIT-OF in COBOL or Rexx' X2B?

What I got going in assembly is mapping against two tables of each possible like this:

```
...
         SR  R1,R1                                          
         IC  R1,BYTE                                        
         IC  R1,HEXTAB(R1)                                  
         LA  R1,BITTAB(R1)                                 
         MVC BITS,0(R1)          
...                         
*                                                           
BYTE     DC  X'3A'                                           
BITS     DS  CL8                                            
HEXTAB   DC  X'0001020903110A19042112290B311A39'            
         DC  X'05412245134D2A550C5D32651B6D3A75'            
         DC  X'06264262237D468514804E8D2B95569D'            
         DC  X'0D495EA533A966B11C886EB93BC176C9'            
         DC  X'071727374353637324837E9B47AF86C7'            
         DC  X'155181AD4FD18ED32C9096DB57D59EE3'            
         DC  X'0E2E4A6A5F92A6BE3498AAE067DDB2EB'            
         DC  X'1D5989B56FD7BAF33CA0C2EE77E5CAF7'            
         DC  X'FF0810182028303840444C545C646C74'            
         DC  X'25617C847F8C949C48A4A8B087B8C0C8'            
         DC  X'16365272829AAEC650ACD0D28FDAD4E2'            
         DC  X'2D6991BD97DFDCEA58B4D6F29FEDE4F6'            
         DC  X'FE0F1F2F3F4B5B6B607B8B93A3A7B7BF'            
         DC  X'357199C5ABCFD9E168BCDEE9B3F1ECF5'            
         DC  X'FD1E3E5A7A8AA2B670C4CED8BBE8F0F4'            
         DC  X'FC3D79A1C3CDE7EFFB78CCE6FACBF9F8'                                                                        
BITTAB   DC C'00000000100000011000001010000011'             
         DC C'10000100100001011000011010000111'             
         DC C'10001000100110001010100010111000'             
         DC C'11001000110110001110100011111001'             
         DC C'00101001001110010101100101101001'             
         DC C'01111001100110101001101110011101'             
         DC C'10011110100111111010101011101011'             
         DC C'01101011111011011110111011111111',C'0000000'
```

But this requires two obnoxiously big tables of the corresponding representations.

Is there any more efficient or less verbose way of doing this?

Comment: Are you able to concatenate strings?  If so, you can shorten the lookup to nibbles rather than whole bytes.  Or, go further and do each bit separately.  What's your criteria for "best"?

Comment: Clever! I like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than have a large table with all possible bit values I used `UNPK` to isolate the nibbles into a byte.  This allowed me to `AND` off the zone portion and then use the remaining nibble as an offset into a local array character strings that are 4 bytes long representing the binary value of the nibble.  This is a first pass but it was my first thought.

If I were doing this for real I'd probably use the `EX` instruction with `TM` to test each bit and simply add '1' or '0' to the character bit representation.  It would save another character array.

To make it more useful it can be optimized to receive 3 parameters which would be the source string, its length and a pointer to the output buffer.  Make the whole thing re-entrant and there would be no need for local storage.

I think this matches your challenge.

Test String is `C"123ABC"` and the output yields

```
   F    1    F    2    F    3    C    1    C    2    C    3
1111 0001 1111 0010 1111 0011 1100 0001 1100 0010 1100 0011
```

```
         PRINT NOGEN                                                   
* ------------------------------------------------------------------- *
*                                                                     *
*  C2B                                                                *
*                                                                     *
*  @author Hogstrom                                                   *
*                                                                     *
*  Process a set of bytes and convert to a displayable '1' and '10'   *
*  to represent the binary value.                                     *
*                                                                     *
* ------------------------------------------------------------------- *
R0       EQU   0                                                       
R1       EQU   1                                                       
R2       EQU   2                                                       
R3       EQU   3                              
R4       EQU   4                                                       
R5       EQU   5                                                       
R6       EQU   6                                                       
R7       EQU   7                                                       
R8       EQU   8                                                       
R9       EQU   9                                                       
R10      EQU   10                                                      
R11      EQU   11                                                      
R12      EQU   12                * Base Register                       
R13      EQU   13                                                      
R14      EQU   14                                                      
R15      EQU   15                                                      
*                                                                      
ASMSKEL  CSECT                                                         
         STM   R14,R12,12(R13)                                         
         LR    R12,R15                                                 
         USING ASMSKEL,R12                                             
*                                                                      
         ST    R13,SaveArea+4                                          
         LA    R0,SaveArea                                             
         ST    R0,8(R13)                                               
         LA    R13,SaveArea                                            
*                                                                      
         OPEN  (SYSOUT,(OUTPUT))                                       
*                                                                      
         LA    R2,L'TEST1        Length of bytes to convert to binary  
         LA    R3,TEST1          Source address of bytes to convert    
         LA    R4,LINE           Where to place the translated bits    
BYTELOOP DS   0H                                                       
         UNPK  NIBBLE,0(2,R3)    unpack two bytes, ignore the second   
         NC    NIBBLE,=X'0F0F'   Turn off zone as its not needed       
         SR    R5,R5             Clear Bit Offset Register             
         IC    R5,NIBBLE         Grab offset                           
         SLL   R5,2              and multiply by 4                     
         LA    R6,CHARBITS                                             
         AR    R6,R5             add offset to correct bits            
         MVC   0(4,R4),0(R6)     move them                             
*                                                                      
         LA    R4,5(R4)          Increment to the next section         
         SR    R5,R5             Clear Bit Offset Register             
         IC    R5,NIBBLE+1       Grab offset                           
         SLL   R5,2              and multiply by 4                     
         LA    R6,CHARBITS                                             
         AR    R6,R5             add offset to correct bits            
         MVC   0(4,R4),0(R6)     move them                             
         LA    R4,5(R4)          Increment to the next section         
         LA    R3,1(R3)          Move to next Byte                     
         BCT   R2,BYTELOOP                                             
*                                                                      
FINISH   DS   0H              
         PUT   SYSOUT,OUTREC                                            
         CLOSE SYSOUT                                                   
*                                                                       
         L     R13,SaveArea+4                                           
         LM    R14,R12,12(R13)                                          
         XR    R15,R15                                                  
         BR    R14                                                      
*                                                                       
SYSOUT   DCB   DSORG=PS,MACRF=(PM),DDNAME=SYSOUT,                      *
               RECFM=FBA,LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=0                            
*                                                                       
NIBBLE   DS    C'   '            Second byte is ignored                 
*                                                                       
TEST1    DC    C'123ABC'                                                
         DC    C' '              Filler Byte to accomodate UNPK         
*                                                                       
OUTREC         DC 0CL133                                                
ASA            DC  C' '                                                 
LINE           DC  CL132' '                                             
*                                                                       
SaveArea       DS  18F                                                  
                LTORG                                                   
CHARBITS  DS  0H        
          DC  C'0000'   
          DC  C'0001'   
          DC  C'0010'   
          DC  C'0011'   
          DC  C'0100'   
          DC  C'0101'   
          DC  C'0110'   
          DC  C'0111'   
          DC  C'1000'   
          DC  C'1001'   
          DC  C'1010'   
          DC  C'1011'   
          DC  C'1100'   
          DC  C'1101'   
          DC  C'1110'   
          DC  C'1111'   
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by using a SLL to move each of the eight bits into the high order bit of a register.  An LTR can be used to check if the register is negative (high order bit = 1).

```
ASMX2B   CSECT ,                                                     
         USING ASMX2B,R15          TEMP BASE                         
         SAVE  (14,12)                                               
         LA    R14,SAVEAREA        A(MY SAVEAREA)                    
         ST    R14,8(R13)          FORWARD-CHAIN MINE FROM CALLER'S  
         ST    R13,4(R14)          BACK-CHAIN CALLER'S FROM MINE     
         LR    R13,R14             SET 13 FOR MY SUBROUTINE CALLS    
         DROP  R15                 FINISHED WITH TEMP BASE           
                                                                     
         LR    R12,R15             SET UP ACTUAL BASE REGISTER       
         USING ASMX2B,R12            AND TELL ASSEMBLER ABOUT IT     
                                                                     
         ICM   R1,B'1000',HEXVAL   HEX VALUE IN HIGH ORDER BYTE      
         LA    R2,BITVAL           POINT TO START OF BITVAL          
         LHI   R3,8                # BITS TO CHECK                   
LOOP     LTR   R1,R1               IS HIGH ORDER BIT ON ?            
         BM    *+8                 YES --->                          
         MVI   0(R2),C'0'          NO, SET BIT SETTING TO 0          
         SLL   R1,1                MOVE NEXT BIT TO HIGH ORDER BIT   
         LA    R2,1(,R2)           POINT TO NEXT VALUE IN BIT VAL    
         BCT   R3,LOOP                                               
                                                                     
         LHI   R15,0                                                 
         L     R13,4(R13)                                            
         RETURN (14,12),RC=(15)    RETURN                            
         YREGS ,                                                     
         LTORG ,                                                     
HEXVAL   DC    X'3A'                                                 
BITVAL   DC    CL8'11111111'                                         
SAVEAREA DS    18F      AREA FOR MY CALLEE TO SAVE & RESTORE MY REGS 
         END
```